# How can I get matrix parameters on the controller's request mapping path?

Tags: spring-mvc

With following controller,

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/abc")
class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    void read(
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "@@?") Map<String, List<String>> matrixVariables
    ) {

    }
}
```

The `matrixVariables` variable is empty.

How can I get matrix parameters, say, from the following URI?

```
http://localhost:8080/abc;x=y
```

How can I matrix parameters on the `/abc` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16516#issuecomment-453414159, the best way to work with is using separate `pathVar` on request mapping paths.

```java
@RequestMapping(path = ".../...{params}")
class Controller {

    public ... read(
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "params", required = false)
            Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    }
}
```